# @Transactional does not work when @Validated

Tags: spring, validation, transactions, aop, spring-aspects

If I add `@Validated` annotation to interface/implementation of my service then the service is not transactional anymore. Stacktrace shows there is no `TransactionInterceptor` but I see only `MethodValidationInterceptor`. If I remove `@Validated` then I see `TransactionInterceptor` and `MethodValidationInterceptor` disappears of course. Are these aspects mutually exclusive?

```
@Service
//@Validated <- here is my problem :)
public interface AdminService {
  String test(String key, String result);
}

public class AdminServiceImpl implements AdminService, BeanNameAware, ApplicationContextAware {

  @Override
  @Transactional(transactionManager = "transactionManager")
  public String test(String key, String result) {

    return "hehe";
  }
}

@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(exposeProxy = true)
@EnableTransactionManagement(order = AspectPrecedence.TRANSACTION_MANAGEMENT_ORDER)
public class AppConfiguration {..}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to validate at your service layer?  The entities you receive at that level should have already *been* validated by the time your service starts to handle them.

Comment: You are probably right but this is not the answer to my question :(

Comment: If the answer turns out to be, "It doesn't make sense to put your validation at that level, move it up," and then you get your transactions back...

Comment: I have just check another thing @Validated also turns off other aspects advising my service so for sure there is something wrong with this behavior :(

Comment: from doc;  a class-level annotation is nevertheless necessary to trigger method validation for a specific bean to begin with. Can also be used as a meta-annotation on a custom stereotype annotation or a custom group-specific validated annotation.

Comment: and the link is https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/annotation/Validated.html

Comment: Could [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48655681/1082681) be your problem? See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39271035/1082681).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**SOLVED**

`@Transactional` and `@Validated` do not work together when a service injecting its own proxy by using `ApplicationContextAware` interface like below:

```
  private String beanName;

  private AdminService self;

  @Override
  public void setBeanName(String beanName) {
    this.beanName = beanName;
  }

  @Override
  public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
    self = applicationContext.getBean(beanName, AdminService.class);
  }
```

During the debugging process I noticed that `setApplicationContext()` method is called by `ApplicationContextAwareProcessor` during the post processing phase in which also `MethodValidationPostProcessor` (`@Validated`) and `AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator` (`@Transactional` and `@Aspects`) wrap the original beans into proxy instances.

Invocation of `getBean()` method in the middle of this process causes the bean not to be fully initialized because some of the post processing operations are not applied. In my case `TransactionInterceptor` was not added.

[image]

For injection of the own proxy to services I finally created specialized Ordered BeaNPostProcessor executed with the `LOWEST_PRECEDENCE` to be sure I operate on a fully initialized bean.