# Kotlin Parameter Annotation is being called before Function Annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I have a RestController defined as follows:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping
import javax.validation.Valid

@RestController
class CaseController(
    private val caseService: CaseService,
    private val remoteFileService: RemoteFileService,
    private val clientService: ClientService
) {
    @PostMapping("/api/v1/cases", consumes = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE])
    @NeedsAuth
    fun createCase(
        @RequestBody @Valid caseCreationRequest: CaseCreationRequest,
        @RequestHeader("Api-Key", required = false) apiKey: String,
    ): ResponseEntity<Case> { }
```

I have defined `NeedsAuth` as an annotation.

The problem is that the `@Valid` annotation is being called before `@NeedsAuth`.

If I send invalid request body with invalid authentication, I receive "Validation Error" as response.

If I send valid request body with invalid authentication, I receive "Authentication Error".

If I remove `@Valid` annotation from code and then send invalid request body with invalid authentication, I receive "Authentication Error".

What I want this to do?

I want it to call @NeedsAuth before @Valid.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Update:

Code related to handling of `@NeedsAuth`:

```
//NeedsAuth.kt
package com.jimdo.debtcollectionservice.adapters.apis.http.auth

@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
annotation class NeedsAuth
```

```
//AuthAspect.kt
package com.jimdo.debtcollectionservice.adapters.apis.http.auth

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder
import org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes

@Component
@Aspect
class AuthAspect {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var authTokenHandler: AuthTokenHandler

    @Before("execution(* *.*(..)) && @annotation(NeedsAuth)")
    fun validateToken(joinPoint: JoinPoint) {
        val request = (RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes() as ServletRequestAttributes).request
        authTokenHandler.authenticateToken(request.getHeader("Api-Key"))
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please describe how you're handing `@NeedsAuth`? Is it your custom annotation with some Spring-managed annotations on it? Or have you implemented `ControllerAdvice` for this annotation?

Comment: @geobreze, it is a custom annotation. I have updated my question to include the code for it.

Comment: Hope this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28975025/advise-controller-method-before-valid-annotation-is-handled